# sharepoint 2013 pass data between custom lists

Tags: workflow, infopath

I am asking the question since this is my first project working with Sharepoint 2013.

Here is the project requirements:
1. I created a custom list for users to enter data in a custom form that is modified by Infopath 2013. 
2. Once the user clicks the 'save' button on the custom form, the workflow is started and the workflow will be waiting for certain users to accept or reject the form.
3. If the form is rejected the user needs to make modifications and the form can be  resubmited.
4. Once the custom form is accepted, the user will be required to submit bimonthly updates on the progress of the request they made based upon the start and end dates submitted on the original form.
5. After the custom form as been accepted, a master/detail will be setup with the master being the accepted form and the bimonthly updates will be details.

Here are my question:
1. I want to pass the information from the accepted form to the master/detail form that will do the following 'Once the custom form is accepted, the user will be required to submit bimonthly updates on the progress of the request they made based upon the start and end dates submitted on the original form'. Would you tell me how to pass the information from the accepted custom form to being the 'master' part of the master/detail form I just mentioned?
Is this a good solution? If you how would you change the design and how would you make these coding changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with workflow.
The workflow goes like this

1. Set the acceptors.
2. upload the form to a list.
3. after the accept/reject set the variable and update the status of the file.
4. Based on the status of the file submitted the workflow can be processed/Iterated.
5. Notify the user or acceptor with a mail about the updates and the assign the flex task with workflow and intimate with mail that the work has been assigned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far. However, I have the following additional questions: 1. What do you mean by 'set the acceptors'? 2. what is the 'assign the flex task'. What is a flex task? 3. Can you tell me and/or point me to a url that will display what you are describing as the solution you just listed above?